# MongoDB - massive amount of MongoCleaner threads

Tags: mongodb

Somehow my java application talking to mongodb ended up with a huge number of parked (sleeping) threads named MongoCleanerXXX which I presume come from the driver. Number of those was ~600. Apparently there were some connection problems with the database which did recover after some time after mongod was restarted.

MongoDB Java driver version is 2.10.1
MongoDB versions is 2.2.0

What could be the reason for this and what I should be doing wrong to cause this as a client app of MongoDB?

Comment: The first thing I would try is upgrading both MongoDB and the Java driver. MongoDB 2.2 is now on 2.2.4 and is available at http://www.mongodb.org/downloads . The Java driver looks like it is at 2.11.2 (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/)

Comment: Before I start fixing things I'd prefer to know what is wrong and why. This is why this question is here.

Comment: I just encountered this issue and have put an answer that I believe to be correct. I hope other struggling folks find it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes we see a lot of these cleanup threads if MongoClient.close() is not called at the appropriate times.

For example:

- When undeploying a webapp (see [JAVA-817](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-817))
- When authentication fails (see [JAVA-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-831))

There were originally some [race conditions around cleaning up these threads](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-306), but this was fixed in version 2.6 of the Java driver.

Comment: thanks, as I mentioned, the driver version is 2.10.1 which I hope includes the corrections from 2.6. I double checked and there is an explicit call to close the Mongo instance when we detect connection loss.

Comment: So it sounds like you're doing all the right things, and you should expect this sort of behaviour and cater for it - it doesn't necessarily point to a problem on your side.

Comment: Hi Trisha. Thanks for taking a look. See my self answer... i found out i wasn't using a static invocation of the MongoClient class after reading the documentation one more time.

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

> The MongoClient class is designed to be thread safe and shared among
>   threads. Typically you create only 1 instance for a given database
>   cluster and use it across your application. If for some reason you
>   decide to create many MongoClient instances, note that:
>
> - all resource usage limits (max connections, etc) apply per MongoClient instance
> - to dispose of an instance, make sure you call MongoClient.close() to clean up resources

Switch your MongoClient invocation to a singleton:

```
static public MongoClient mongoClientInstance = null;
public static synchronized MongoClient getMongoClientInstance(String host) {
    if (mongoClientInstance == null) {
        try {
            mongoClientInstance = new MongoClient(host);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mongoClientInstance;
}
```

Seems to work great.