# MongoCleaner Threads Count goes very high

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

Somehow MongoDB application ended up with the huge number of MongoCleanerXXX thread in "Timed Waiting" status , which finally cause a "OutOfMemory - unable to create new native thread" issue. I am creating a singleton object for MongoClient & dataStore Object and use Morphia for CURD operation.

I am using Playframework, MongoDB-2.6 , mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar, morphia-0.99.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Below is the code to create datastore object.

```java
public enum AppMongoConfig {
    INSTANCE;

    private MongoClient mongo;
    private Morphia morphia = new Morphia();;
    private Datastore datastore;
    private String ip;
    private String schema;
    private DB db;
    private int port;

    private AppMongoConfig() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        Logger.info(" ##### Initializing mongo app db ######");
        this.ip = Play.application().configuration()
                .getString("appMongoDBHost");
        this.schema = Play.application().configuration()
                .getString("appMongoDBSchema");
        this.port = Play.application().configuration().getInt("appMongoDBPort");
        try {
            this.mongo = new MongoClient(this.ip, this.port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        this.db = this.mongo.getDB(this.schema);
        this.datastore = this.morphia.createDatastore(this.mongo,
                this.db.getName());
        Logger.info(" ##### Initialized mongo app db ######");
    }

    public Datastore getDs() {
        return this.datastore;
    }
}
```

And this is how i access the DB

```java
AppMongoConfig.INSTANCE.getDs()
            .find(FileUploadStatusInfo.class).field("pollingId")
            .equal(pollingId).get();
```

I took the thread dump for my java process to monitor the threads, My thread count keeps on increasing and sometimes reaches till 20K. Out Of 20K, almost 19950 threads are "MongoCleaner" threads. Below is what i see in threaddump.

```
    "MongoCleaner1202732389" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f360418a000 nid=0x17c6 waiting on condition [0x00007f35ee2e2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$CursorCleanerThread.run(Mongo.java:773)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"MongoCleaner298435004" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f36081a4000 nid=0x17c4 waiting on condition [0x00007f35ee3e3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$CursorCleanerThread.run(Mongo.java:773)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"MongoCleaner1971787750" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f36081a2000 nid=0x17c2 waiting on condition [0x00007f35ee4e4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$CursorCleanerThread.run(Mongo.java:773)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

What could be the reason for this and am i doing anything wrong to cause this as a client app of MongoDB?

This issue still persist, Has anyone found and answer yet.

Comment: Not a solution but have you thought about upgrading Morphia? Your version is ancient (3 or 4 years I guess). Not sure it makes much sense to debug that.

Comment: Yes i have tried to update that to .102 , but results the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is `INSTANCE` from [EnumJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327409/mongodb-massive-amount-of-mongocleaner-threads)? Maybe that's the reason why the setup of `AppMongoConfig` looks a bit unusual to me.

Whatever you're doing, `MongoClient` should be static. Your issue sounds like you're creating multiple / too many instances. See also [MongoDB - massive amount of MongoCleaner threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327409/mongodb-massive-amount-of-mongocleaner-threads)

Comment: INSTANCE is same as public static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton(); I am using an enum to implement the singleton object , so my mongoClient & dataStore is a singleton object.  Sorry for the late response, i was away from my work for few days.